# Error connect Mysql with SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Estoy intentando acceder a los datos de la Base de datos de Mysql con SpringBoot:
Pero me da error, **nunca he**  accedido, por tanto soy totalmente nuevo, estoy siguiendo tutoriales (5-6), ninguno ha funcionado.

La idea es poner en el navegador una dirección y que me devuelva la lista de usuarios.

Empezamos: pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
               <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                 <version>6.0.5</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
               </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

interface

```
package prueba;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RepositorioUsuariosDB extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {

}
```

Entidad/Clase

```
package prueba;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Usuario {
 @Id
 private Long id;
 private String nombre;
 private String password;

 public Usuario() {}

 public Usuario(String nombre, String password ) {
     this.nombre = nombre;
     this.password = password;
 }

 public Long getId() {
     return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
     this.id = id;
 }

 public String getNombre() {
     return nombre;
 }

 public void setNombre(String nombre) {
     this.nombre = nombre;
 }


 public String getPassword() {
     return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
     this.password = password;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "Usuario{" +
             "id=" + id +
             ", nombre='" + nombre + '\''+
             '}';
 }
}
```

Configuración

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/localservice?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= miname
spring.datasource.password= mipass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect 
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Código de error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-29 11:01:06.260 ERROR 12404 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

---

```
http://ledze.mx/index.php/10-spring-boot/restful/12-spring-boot-datarest-conexion-con-mysql-y-manejo-con-jpa
```

Estaba siguiendo ese tutorial , pero modifiqué 2 cosas:

Los campos en la BBDD se los he puesto como en la Entity "id,nombre,password" por tanto en el interface no le he puesto lo del findEmail.

De momento es para recoger datos, **ver como funciona**, trasiego de información, y sobre todo, enterarme bien.

http://localhost:8080/usuarios No se puede acceder

**Actualizo** con las nuevas dependencia y el nuevo código de error

Comment: Has copiado  JDBC de sql server en las librerías de tu proyecto?

Comment: `Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ` parece que no tienes la librería JDBC incorporada, o al menos no apuntas correctamente a dicha librería.

Comment: He cambiado las dependencias porque en el tutorial venia <version>Released</version> ahora el error ha cambiado.

Comment: ¿Qué clase implementa RepositorioUsuariosDB? ¿Puedes poner su código?

Comment: Por favor, no vayas cambiando la misma pregunta según te vayan respondiendo las dudas; si una duda ya está solucionada y te aparece una distinta crea una nueva pregunta. Es imposible dar una respuesta correcta si la pregunta cambia.

Answer (score 3):

En tu `pom.xml` tienes:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Esto carga la última versión de Release de la librería `mysql-connector-java` en tu classpath al ejecutar el programa via maven.

En la configuración tienes

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Pero mirando [la documentación de `mysql-connector-java`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html), te explica que en ese jar el driver se llama `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. [Según este changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html), la clase se renombró al pasar a la versión 8.0 del jar.

Probablemente el ejemplo se probó antes del release de la versión 8.0 y ahora ya no funciona.

La solución debería ser cambiar la configuración:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: He cambiado las dependencias porque en el tutorial venia <version>Released</version> ahora el error ha cambiado.

Comment: Por favor, no vayas cambiando la misma pregunta según te vayan respondiendo las dudas; si una duda ya está solucionada y te aparece una distinta crea una nueva pregunta. Es imposible dar una respuesta "correcta" si la pregunta cambia.